# New memory store with an array without an object

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have an array without an object within it and I am trying to add data to my store. I have this:

```
options: [0:value,1:value]
```

when I know I need this:

```
options: [{0:value,1:value}]
```

Is there any way I can modify this with a utility somewhere in dojo or with JS? I have no access to changing the web service.

[image]

Comment: are you getting those as strings like `options: ['0:value','1:value']`.

Comment: 0: "value", 1: "value"

Comment: but in a string every thing am I right?

Comment: The indexes are no surrounded with quotes. Just the values.

Comment: do you have string like this `options = '[0:"value",1:"value"]'`

Comment: the thing you are showing doesn't seem to be a proper JSON value also, how man

Comment: So, what you want is to translate `[ 'a', 'b' ]` to `[{ 0: 'a', 1: 'b' }]`? What does this have to do with a store?

Comment: I want to be able to use FilterSelect dijit to sort through these. There are potentially hundreds.

Comment: Then the object you want is not going to work either, you need seperate objects for all of the items.

Comment: Afraid of that. Does completely require a store?

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same line already... to display each item individually in your filteringselect, you need an array of objects, not an array of strings nor an array of a single object. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not even valid JSON or JavaScript syntax you're asking, you either define objects, for example:

```js
{ name: "value" }
```

Or you use the array syntax:

```js
[ "value1", "value2", "value3" ]
```

---

After a bit of puzzling in the comment I suppose you want to use your array of strings as the dropdown items of a `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`.
Well, that's indeed possible by translating the array first into an array of objects (since that is usually required for the widgets to work).

The best module for translating arrays is the `dojo/_base/array:map()` function. Which we could use in your case to do:

```js
var output = arrUtils.map(input, function(item, idx) {
    return {
        label: item,
        id: idx
    };
});
```

This will translate an array like this:

```js
[ 'value1', 'value2' ]
```

into:

```js
[{ label 'value1', id: 0 }, { label: 'value2', id: 1 }]
```

Which you can then use inside the `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`, for example:

```js
new FilteringSelect({
    store: new Memory({
        data: output
    }),
    labelAttr: 'label',
    searchAttr: 'label'
}, "mySelect");
```

Which should work fine, as you can see in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/au5Fr/

---

To answer your question if you need a store, then the answer would be yes. `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` does not have an option called `options`, that one is only available on `dijit/form/Select` as far as I know.

Comment: Your output solution now returned everything as such {0: "unwantedDiscarded_s", 1: "part_max_used"} which is what I need for a FilterSelect. Testing will mark as answered shortly